# Checking previous SMS senders Django/Twilio

Tags: python, django, twilio

I'm trying to keep track of the answers from users who sends a "password" into the Twilio app so they can answer a series of questions. First, it'll probably be best to check that "from_number" exists in the database, then create a new Caller if it isn't.

In models.py:

```
class Callers(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField()
    from_number = models.CharField()
    last_question = models.CharField(max_length=1, default="0")
```

In views.py:

```
def HelloThere(request):
    body = request.REQUEST.get('Body', None)
    from_number = request.REQUEST.get("From",None)

    if Caller.objects.filter(from_number == from_number):
        if last_question == "0":
            caller = Caller(message = "first question". last_question = "1")
            caller.save()
            return HttpResponse(str(resp))
        if last_question == '1':
            # so on and so forth
    else:
        caller = Caller(body=body, from_number=from_number, last_question='0')
        caller.save()
        message = "What is the password?"
```

I don't think I can use request.user.is_authenticated().

/Is it a bad idea to have so many of the same field names? "body=body=Body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First about the model:

```
class Callers(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField()
    from_number = models.CharField()
    last_question = models.IntegerField(default=0) # if you have more than 10 question then I guess using IntegerField is better here
```

Then the view:

```
def hello_there(request):  # this is a function, so use lower case with underscore for name
    body = request.REQUEST.get('Body', None)
    from_number = request.REQUEST.get("From",None)

    try:
        caller = Caller.objects.get(from_number=from_number) # using get() is better than filter here since I guess you want unique caller field in DB, right?
    except Caller.DoesNotExist:
        caller = None

    if caller:
        if caller.last_question == 0:
            # update the caller ?
            caller.last_question = 1
            caller.body = 'Something'
            caller.save()
            # ... your code ...
            return HttpResponse(str(resp))
        if last_question == 1:
            # so on and so forth
            # if you have repeated process here, make a function to update caller to be DRY
    else:
        new_caller = Caller(body=body, from_number=from_number, last_question=0)
        new_caller.save()
        message = "What is the password?"
```

`request.user.is_authenticated()` is only for `User` model so you can't use it. And it's okay to use same name for different things, for example `body` in your view can be variable or argument. If it isn't clear for you then you can pick different name then.

Hope it helps!

Comment: double checking, the Caller in view.py should be "Callers" right?

Comment: Yeah, forget I asked that. Just have to be consistent. You rock dude

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't notice the model is `Callers`. Normally I would name the model singular with capital case, like `Caller`, and the app name plural and all lower cases, such as `callers`.

Comment: For some reason after I tried to Syncdb to create a table for Caller, the entire views import system broke. The error I get is ViewDoesNotExist, and it looks for HelloThere from "appname.views." With an added trailing period. Some people have had this problem but it never got solved in SO. Have you ever encountered this?

Comment: No I haven't. The fastest way to do is to flush the DB and run syncdb again. Remember that syncdb is not used for changing data of an existing table. If you have other problem, please post another question

Comment: Weird, syncing created the issue with the trailing period but I just rebuilt the app and every thing works perfectly!